# How to use Swagger UI's responseInterceptor in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swagger-ui

I am working with Swagger UI and the following works fine in jsx with React.

```
<SwaggerUI
    url={SPEC_FILE}
    responseInterceptor={(response: Response) => {
      //console.log("response ", response);
      if (response.url === REQUEST_URL && response.status === 200) {
        setData(response.data);
      }
    }}
  />
```

However when using the above in React with TypeScript, I get the following error at `responseInterceptor`:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<SwaggerUIProps>): SwaggerUI', gave the following error.
    Type '(response: Response) => void' is not assignable to type '(res: Response) => Response | Promise<Response>'.
      Types of parameters 'response' and 'res' are incompatible.
        Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok, redirected, status, and 12 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SwaggerUIProps, context?: any): SwaggerUI', gave the following error.
    Type '(response: Response) => void' is not assignable to type '(res: Response) => Response | Promise<Response>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(27, 5): The expected type comes from property 'responseInterceptor' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SwaggerUI> & Readonly<SwaggerUIProps> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(27, 5): The expected type comes from property 'responseInterceptor' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SwaggerUI> & Readonly<SwaggerUIProps> & Readonly<...>'
```

Anyone has ideas how to use Swagger UI's `responseInterceptor` in TypeScript?

Comment: Here is an example code with error: https://codesandbox.io/s/swagger-ui-react-xfnsr?file=/src/index.tsx:295-314

Answer (score 1):

Nice folks at typescript group helped me, so i thought to share the answer here, i just needed to return the response.

```
<SwaggerUI
    url="https://api.mna.dev.spsapps.net/swagger/?format=openapi"
    responseInterceptor={response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data);
      }
      return response; // this is what i needed to do.
    }}
  />
```